# Parse Cloud Code - Missing attributes from response object

Tags: parse-platform, attributes, cloud, response

Firstly, sorry if this is already answered, but I couldn't find it.

I'm having some trouble retrieving all attributes from a Parse response.

I found this select() method on the documentation, which would do exactly what I need, pointing out which columns should be returned, but it seem to 
take no effect.

The bit of code

```
var answersQuery    = new Parse.Query("answer");
answersQuery.select(["objectId", "description", "category_id", "sale_id", "image_url"]);
answersQuery.equalTo("previous_question_id", {
    __type: "Pointer",
    className: "question",
    objectId: questionId
});
answersQuery.find().then(function(answersData) {
    if (typeof(answersData) != "undefined") {
        var answers = [];
        for (var i in answersData) {
            answers.push({
                id         : answersData[i].id,
                sale_id    : answersData[i].get("sale_id"),
                image_url  : answersData[i].get("image_url"),
                category_id: answersData[i].get("category_id"),
                description: answersData[i].get("description")
            });
        }
        response.success({
            answers : answers
        });
    } else {
        response.error("answers not found");
    }
});
```

But the return I get always contains just the "id" and the "description" attributes

```
{"result":{"answers":[{"description":"COMPRAS","id":"x3pS8sadDS"},{"description":"CINEMA","id":"MVHwJqifzE"}]}}
```

If I change the "id" to something like "asdf" it will reflect in the response, so I'm sure I'm dealing iwth the same object I can see in the response.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Does the `answers` table has too many fields? Have you tried not specifying fields (I mean, to using the select statement)?

Comment: The answer table has 10 columns and 21 rows. Edit: Now I noticed when I remove the select() call, I get the order of the attributes different. With th select() call it was id first than description, now description comes first.

Comment: That's really strange - Are you sure the column names weren't misspelled?  Anyway, it should be ok to just leave the select out for this amount of fields.